# Фильтрация элементов массива с n-элементов по заданному критерию с реверсированием порядка

Tags: php, сортировка, динамические-массивы, фильтрация

Предположим, у нас есть строка "Алала1234.Марк!Михаил?Елена..."

---

Нам нужно:

---

1) преобразовать в массив, разбить массив на строки, так, чтобы знаки препинания, в т.ч. неодносимвольные типа "?!" или "..." являлись разделителями

---

2) поменять разделители местами, чтобы вышло "Алала1234...Марк?Михаил!Елена."

Comment: Можно взглянуть на вашу попытку решения проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбиваете строку по шаблону на массив слов и символов по отдельности. Массив символов "переворачиваете", и в цикле собираете новую результирующую строку:

```
$str = 'Алала1234.Марк!Михаил?Елена...';

$marks = array_reverse(preg_split('~[^[:punct:]]+~', $str, -1, 1));
$result = '';

foreach (preg_split('~[[:punct:]]+~', $str, -1, 1) as $k => $word) {
    $result .= $word . ($marks[$k] ?? '');
}

echo $result;
```

Результат:
    Алала1234...Марк?Михаил!Елена.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне как-то даже в голову не пришло взять preg_split, мучался с preg_replace.